# Same function in several Entity Repositories without Base Repository?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Let's say I have a set of entities in Doctrine and one custom repository for each.

For many of these entities I have a chain of extensions, let's say MyEntity extends GenericEntity extends StandardEntity extends BaseEntity and the Repositories are following the same approach.

In my case this is fully valid because according to OOP MyEntity is just a very specific version of the common base classes.

Now I have a repository function like this:

```
    public function getCount()
{
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('COUNT(me)');
    $qb->from('MyEntity', 'me');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();

}
```

It would be great to have the same functionality for several entities and I won't to avoid code duplication.

My options to my understanding:

1. **Interface** iCountableRepository: Only partially helpful as I require implementation in class.
2. **Extending** CountEntityRepository: Doesn't fit in my chain of extensions, multi-inheritance isn't possible in PHP too
3. **Trait** CountableRepository:

This sounds like the most useful approach to me. But is it possible and recommended to have something like:

```
    public function getCount()
    {
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('COUNT(me)');
    $qb->from($this->_entityName, 'me');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();

    }
```

Is 'this' possible within a trait?

Or what might be another way to build generic Repository Function which can be 'injected' into some chosen Repositories?

Comment: a trait will work just fine. KNP labs uses it in their DoctrineBehaviours bundle. (https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#filterable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A trait is totally fine for something like this.
But you can also extend the base repository. I don't really understand why this would not be possible. I think you should be able to do this:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Repository;

use Countable;

class BaseEntityRepository extends EntityRepository implements Countable
{
    /**
     * Count items in this repository
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function count()
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('b');
        $qb->select('COUNT(b)');
        return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
    }
}
```

And then:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Repository;

class StandardEntityRepository extends BaseEntityRepository
{

}
```

And then:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Repository;

class GenericEntityRepository extends StandardEntityRepository
{

}
```

And:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Repository;

class MyEntity extends GenericEntityRepository
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks and I agree - obviously I wasn't full clear in my question. This approach works here of course, but what if MyEntityA extends from GenericA/StandardA and MyEntityB extends from GenericB and so on. So if there's no common root element. But you already helped me when a trait is fine! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @LBA That your entity classes don't extend each other does not mean that you cannot use the same base repository class. But a trait is maybe even better...